# What could be the possible reasons for segmentation fault?

Tags: multithreading, c++11, segmentation-fault, gdb

The code snippet is following:

```
ValueMapIter valueIter;    
for (valueIter = activeValues->begin(); valueIter !=activeValues->end(); ++valueIter)
{
        cout << "Before First" << endl;
        cout << "sizeactivevalue:" << activeValues->size() << endl;
        cout << "first:" << valueIter->first << "Second:" << valueIter->second << endl;
}
```

The PROGRAM output while running with gdb is:
The program outputs

Before First

sizeactivevalue:10

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x2aaaac8ad940 (LWP 8346)]
0x000000000043e732 in ValueManager::InsertModValue (this=0xd455c90, Id=4615, PId=7753, eId=1100000010570903, iId=2, inId=44301, pe=830795, t=25, bl=2, ste=3, sde=2)
    at /home/pathtofile/valuemanager.cpp:304
304     cout << "first:" << valueIter->first << "Second:" << valueIter->second << endl;
```

How can it receive a segmentation fault, while I have a local copy of ValueMapIter and it ran on the code correctly previously.

The program is multithreaded; there is only one activeValues map. The snippet is inside the InsertModValues function. 
The size of the activeValue map is 10 then How can the iter not have a valid first element ?

Comment: The biggest and most common reason is probably [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Exactly what leads to UB (as it's shortened to) depends. Maybe dereferencing a null pointer? Maybe it's attempting to free memory twice or to free memory you haven't allocated? Maybe you're dereferencing a pointer that has been unallocated previously? There are many reasons behind UB, all of them bad, many of them leading to crashes, and sometime, if you're "lucky" it might even *seem* to work.

Comment: As to help you solve your problem, you have to give us more information, like the declaration of `activeValues`, what `valueIter->first` is, and what `valueIter->second` is. Also, are you removing elements from `activeValues` from other threads without locking? Doing this print-out without locking? Generally not locking anywhere?

Comment: As an addendum to my previous comment, it's not only removing from one thread that can cause problems without synchronization, some containers may invalidate iterators when adding elements too. You might want to check e.g. [this container reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container).